# How to refer to a series of pairs?

Tags: articles, singular-vs-plural, ellipsis, lists

To enumerate all the pairs of jeans I have, using commas and without repeating "pair", may I put it like this:

> I have a pink, a black, a grey, two dark and a blue pairs of jeans.

Should I replace the determiner "a" by the numeral "one"? 
The seems really problematic.